# Bash script for editing multiple text files

Tags: macos

I would like some guide and help for this:

1. I have a text file with names listed in it. I will call it “source file”
2. I have multiple text files scattered in folders and sub folders
3. I would like to know how to make a script that would automatically add SPECIFIC LINE to every text file (in subfolders of chosen target folder) that contains exact name listed in “source file”

More detailed/Example:

I have a names.txt that contains many names. I want to find all the text files in target folder and it’s subfolders that contains names listed in names.txt and in those files automatically add “FALSE” line (in front or after specific existing line).

Comment: Traverse the directory tree with `find` to find those files whose names are in the source file, and execute a script to add the desired line to the file.  Use a text editor to make the script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to look for names defined INSIDE all the files in target directory and need to write only to those which are listed in source file...

Comment: Please provide the XML source file.

Comment: Add the line "FALSE" *where*? As first line, as last line, as line 73?

Comment: I gave .xml as example, it might be .txt or .csv or any kind of text file which has list of names divided by , or ; or similar. FALSE would have to be added in a line before or line after existing line which I would define (which of course exists)

Comment: Don't provide specs in comments. Update your question to provide specifics that can be used to reproduce the circumstance.

Comment: If you want folks to help you, it's generally best to just make it easy for them instead of being unhelpful and vague... else they'll just lose interest. Nobody wants to write code to cover comma-separated, tab-separated, space-separated files that may be CSV or XML and may need something added here or maybe there or maybe somewhere else. It kind of loses the point of how to do it in a forest of code to cover unnecessary eventualities.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don’t understand what you mean exactly. I am trying to describe what I would like to do and I might be totally wrong but it seems to me that what I ask is something that everybody who knows basics of coding should at least have idea how to do it. I am pretty illiterate that way but I hope that someone would be helpful to at least give some hints on what and how to in coding terms so I can understand better what I need to look for.

Comment: Your question is very poorly stated. Does your source file have 1 filename per line? Or several per line? Separated by what? If the word `fred` appears in your source file, does that mean you should only edit a file called `fred`, or also `freddy`? What about a file called `fred.txt`? Or a file called `sub1/subdir2/fred`? Or a file called `simon` with the word `fred` inside it on line2? Where do I insert something? At a given line number? I might use `sed`? After a word? I might use `awk`. What if the word occurs twice - do I insert twice? Or just once?

Comment: 1. source file contains only names; one line contains one name; no separators 2. in source file every line has unique name 3. if ANY of the unique names from the  source file is contained in ANY text file found in target folder/subfolders ALL of that files has to be edited so the word "FALSE" is added in one line before a line that contains: "[END]"